# Does $X((X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty)$ equal $X(X^{-1}y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be some matrix and $y$ be a vector of appropriate length.

I've seen someone use the expression

$X(X^{-1}y)$

instead of

$X((X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty)$

in the context of ordinary least squares estimation.

Are these expressions equal? and if so, can someone walk me through the process of getting from the latter to the former?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two expressions are not in general equal. However, the context of least-squares is actually quite a special case, and several assumptions are typically made. Most importantly, in the linear least-squares problem
$$
Xy = b,
$$
it is often assumed that $X$ is a matrix of full column rank (that is, the map $y \mapsto Xy$ is injective). This is because this is the case in which the linear least-squares problem has a unique least-squares solution $\hat{y}$, such that
$$
\|X\hat{y} - b\|_2 \le \| Xy - b\|_2
$$
for every vector $y$.

When it is indeed the case that $X$ has full column rank, then $X^T X$ is an invertible matrix, and therefore $(X^T X)^{-1} X^T$ is a *left-inverse*, also called a *pseudo-inverse*, to $X$. This is only a true inverse if $X$ is square. Typically, to distinguish from the true inverse, we use a different symbol, such as
$$
X^{+} : = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T.
$$
With this notation, then the linear least-squares problem has the unique solution $\hat{y} = X^{+} b$. The bottom-line, then, is that $X^{+}$ gives the general solution to the problem, but when you know that $X$ is square and invertible, then you can naturally replace this with $X^{-1}$.

Comment: Brilliant, very helpful, thanks

Comment: I have noticed that $X(X^{-1}y)$ provides more stable results upon implementation (I use matlab), than $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ when the matrix is close to being singular. Do you know anything about this? I suppose it's the number of operations. And what is your opinion on using $X(X^{-1}y)$ for implementations?

Comment: @user318895 Why are you computing $XX^{-1} y$? If $X$ is indeed square and invertible, then $XX^{-1} = I$. If you're actually doing $XX^{+}y$, then yes, Matlab knows more efficient ways to compute $X^{+}$ than to do $(X^T X)^{-1} X^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equal, and both equal to $y$. Here are the equalities you are searching for:
$$
X((X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty) = X(X^{-1}(X^T)^{-1}X^Ty) = X(X^{-1}y) = XX^{-1}y = y.
$$

Comment: +1: if the question has the symbol $X^{-1}$ the matrix is surely square and invertible.

Comment: @Jonas, I think in the OP's case, it must be an abuse of notation; if $X^{-1}$ existed then there would be no need for considering a least-squares solution. Otherwise what would be the point of even writing $XX^{-1}$ when you could just write $I$.

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong Indeed, there wouldn't be the need. But this is not the question, and so it is clearly as I say.

Comment: @Jonas I don't think so. At face value, e.g. the title of the question, yes, but really the OP's question is "Why does someone use $X(X^{-1}y)$ instead of $X(X^T X)^{-1} X^{T}y$"? And the answer to that question is that one is a special case of the other.

Comment: How is $X^{-1}$ defined for a non-square matrix?

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong Fine, I respect your opinion, but of course I completely disagree.

Comment: @Hugo It's not. Your answer is correct. But in the context that the OP mentioned, what should be clarified is that the least-squares projector $(X^T X)^{-1} X^T$ gives the general solution, while $X^{-1}$ is equal to this only when $X$ is indeed square.

Comment: I see that my question was ambiguous, but Christopher Wong hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 0):

In general, they are not equal. For one thing, the design matrix $X$ would have to be square in order for $XX^{-1}$ to even make sense. Also, $X$ need not be invertible even if it is square. OTOH, in the rare instance that $X$ is square *and* invertible, then the identity holds, as proved by Hugo.